# String Functions: Strcat()

Tags: c++

I'm currently writing a program that uses string functions. I need some advice/hints on how I can display "Hello World" and its length with myStrcat() in main(). I'm new to programming and any support would be greatly appreciated.

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int myStrlen(char str1[])
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; str1[i] != '\0'; i++)
    str1[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}

int myStrcat(char str2[], char str3[])
{

}

int myStrcpy(char str4[], char str5[])
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; str5[i] != '\0'; i++)
    str4[i] = str5[i];
    str4[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 11;
    char s1[SIZE] = "Hello";
    char s2[SIZE] = "World";

    cout << "s1: " << " " << s1 << endl << endl; ///Should display "Hello"
    cout << "The length of s1: " << myStrlen(s1) << endl << endl;

    cout << "Doing strcat(s1, s2) " << endl;
    myStrcat(s1, s2);
    cout << "s1: " << " " << s1 << endl; /// Should display "Hello World"
    cout << "The length of s1: " << myStrlen(s1) << endl << endl;

    cout << "Doing strcpy(s1, s2) " << endl;
    myStrcpy(s1, s2);
    cout << "s1: " << " " << s1 << endl; /// Should display "World"
    cout << "The length of s1: " << myStrlen(s1) << endl << endl;
```

My Output:

```
s1:  Hello

The length of s1: 5

Doing strcat(s1, s2)
s1:
The length of s1: 0

Doing strcpy(s1, s2)
s1:  World
The length of s1: 5
```

Line 6 and 7 are suppose to display Hello World and its length (which is 11).

Comment: And it's really time that you learn how to debug your code. A good editor that does automatic indentation together with some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) should go a long way. Otherwise use an actual *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement (especially your `myStrlen` function).

Comment: Size 11 is one letter too short to fit "Hello World" since there are no room for terminating null '\0' character.

Comment: _how I can display "Hello World" and its length with myStrcat() in main()._ "display"? (Might be bad wording.) Assuming, your `myStrlen()` and `myStrcpy()` would work correctly (what I didn't check), use `myStrlen()` to get the length `len` of `str2`. Copy `str3` to `str2 + len`. But, I recommend to fix the errors mentioned in the above comments first. Undefined behavior can drive you crazy - it's best fixed ASAP.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you try to program these functions yourself? They are easily available from libraries.

Comment: @Yunnosch It's September - new classes have started. ;-) I assume it's homework.

Comment: @Scheff Me too. But I want to be told. Especially in case of "please fill in complete code for my empty functions" cases.

Comment: Which part of the shown code is by yourself? Which part of the shown code comes directly from requirements/teacher? I would like to catch them at fault...

Comment: What? `str1[i] = '\0';` in `Strlen` is zeroing your string while finding the length??

Comment: Don't use c style strings if you are starting programming. Use [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). It's much simpler to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of not just quite right beginning to each of your functions. Firstly, let's think about the returns for each. `myStrlen` should return `size_t` instead of `int`. C++ designates a size_type for counters, measuring, etc.. The remaining functions should return `char*` (or `nullptr` on failure).

Looking at your `myStrlen` function where you have

```
for (i=0; str1[i] != '\0'; i++)
str1[i] = '\0';
```

You are setting every character in `str1` to the *nul-character* because you are applying the loop to the next expression. You should not be worrying about nul-terminating anything within `myStrlen` -- you are just counting characters. So you can rewrite it as follows:

```
size_t myStrlen (const char *str)
{
    size_t l = 0;
    for (; str[l]; l++) {}
    return l;
}
```

Your `myStrcpy` looks workable, though you should always validate your input parameters are not `nullptr` before using them -- I leave that to you. Since you have a `myStrlen` function, you can simply use that along with `memcpy` to create your `myStrcpy` function as:

```
char *myStrcpy (char *dest, const char *src)
{
    size_t len = myStrlen(src);
    return (char *)memcpy (dest, src, len + 1);
}
```

(**note:** traditionally you have source (`src`) and destination (`dest`) parameters when copying or concatenating)

For your `myStrcat` function, you are just using the `myStrlen` function to find the offset in `dest` to append `src`, so you really just need a call to `myStrlen` and then a call to `myStrcpy` to copy `src` to that offset in `dest`, e.g.

```
char *myStrcat (char *dest, const char *src)
{
    size_t len = myStrlen (dest);
    return myStrcpy (dest + len, src);
}
```

In your `main()`, if you want a space between `"Hello"` and `"World"`, then `const int SIZE = 11;` is one too-low to hold the concatenated string `"Hello World"` which would require `12-bytes` (including the *nul-terminating* character). *Do Not Skimp* on buffer size. `128` is plenty small.

Remaining with your `main()` but updating `SIZE = 12;` and adding a space between `"Hello"` and `"World"` with an additional call to `myStrcat`, you could do the following:

```
int main (void)
{
    const int SIZE = 12;    /* too short by 1 if you add space between */
    char s1[SIZE] = "Hello";
    char s2[SIZE] = "World";

    std::cout << "s1: " << " " << s1 << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The length of s1: " << myStrlen(s1) << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Doing strcat(s1, s2) " << std::endl;
    myStrcat(s1, " ");
    myStrcat(s1, s2);
    std::cout << "s1: " << " " << s1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The length of s1: " << myStrlen(s1) << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Doing strcpy(s1, s2) " << std::endl;
    myStrcpy(s1, s2);
    std::cout << "s1: " << " " << s1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The length of s1: " << myStrlen(s1) << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

(**note:** don't include `using namespace std;`, it is just bad form in this day and age)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$./bin/mystrcpy
s1:  Hello

The length of s1: 5

Doing strcat(s1, s2)
s1:  Hello World
The length of s1: 11

Doing strcpy(s1, s2)
s1:  World
The length of s1: 5
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

First you should read [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Don't use c style strings if you are starting programming. Use [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). It's much simpler to use.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int myStrlen(const std::string &str) {
    return str.length();
}

int myStrcat(std::string &str1, const std::string &str2) {
    str1 += str2;
    str1.length();
}

int myStrcpy(std::string &str1, const std::string &str2) {
    str1 = str2;
    return str1.length();
}

int main() {
    std::string s1 = "Hello";
    std::string s2 = "World";

    std::cout << "s1:  " << s1 << "\n\n"; ///Should display "Hello"
    std::cout << "The length of s1: " << myStrlen(s1) << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "Doing strcat(s1, s2) " << '\n';
    myStrcat(s1, s2);
    std::cout << "s1:  " << s1 << '\n'; /// Should display "Hello World"
    std::cout << "The length of s1: " << myStrlen(s1) << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "Doing strcpy(s1, s2) " << '\n';
    myStrcpy(s1, s2);
    std::cout << "s1:  " << s1 << '\n'; /// Should display "World"
    std::cout << "The length of s1: " << myStrlen(s1) << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```